# Freezer frosts up about every 2 weeks

Tags: refrigerator

I am being told that the reason my freezer builds up ice and stops cooling the fridge down is because I leave the door open too long  getting food out. Maybe maybe..2 full mins.

Comment: is it supposed to be self-defrosting?  Those that ice up actually keep food the best.

Answer (score 3):

Leaky door seals.

Air is getting in and out of the fridge through door seals that aren't tight.  They have cracked or gotten stiff to where they no longer mate tightly.  Get a clean dollar bill and hold it in the gap while you close the door. How stiff does it come out? Do that all around the door.  You can also watch for mold and mildew at spots around the door.

Door seals can be purchased for many refrigerators.

Alternately, the defrost system may be malfunctioning.

Comment: And 2mins is a long time, if repeated several times a day

Comment: Can you still do that with a dollar bill? I thought that due to inflation you need to use at least a $5 bill to check the seals these days :-)

Comment: And here I was taught to just use a piece of typing paper.

Comment: Check the drain and be sure it is not plugged. If so flush it out by using a turkey baster and hot water.